# How to prove that $|||y |||$ is continuous using the usual basis of $\Bbb R^{n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity

How to prove that $|||y |||$ is continuous on $\Bbb R^{n}$ by using the usual basis of $\Bbb R^{n}$

By the way, $||| \cdot |||$ is a norm on $\Bbb R^{n}$

I can show this by using triangle inequality. But I dont know how to utilize usual basis. Please help me. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\nrm}[1]{\left|\left|\left|{#1}\right|\right|\right|}
\newcommand{\ip}[1]{\left\langle{#1}\right\rangle}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left|{#1}\right|}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\|{#1}\right\|}$Let $\{e_1,\dotsc,e_n\}$ denote the standard ordered basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $\norm{x}:=\sqrt{\ip{x,x}}$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$,
$$
 \nrm{x} = \nrm{ \sum_k \ip{e_k,x}e_k } \leq \sum_k \abs{\ip{e_k,x}}\nrm{e_k} \leq \sum_k \norm{x}\nrm{e_k} = \left(\sum_k \nrm{e_k}\right)\norm{x}.
$$
So, what can you now conclude?

Comment: Hmm Will I use the definiton of countinity? I cannot produce any idea

Comment: A function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, by definition, if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that if $\|x-y\| < \delta$, $|f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$. Now, given that $|||\cdot|||$ is a norm, what is the relation between $|\;|||x|||-|||y|||\;|$ and $|||x-y|||$?

Comment: $|||x-y|||<δ$ implies that  $| |||x|||-|||y||| |=|f(x)-f(y)|<ε$ Is it right?

Comment: No, no. Since $|||\cdot|||$ is a norm, you can apply the inverse triangle inequality (and the computation above) to conclude that
$$
 |\;|||x|||-|||y|||\;| \leq |||x-y||| \leq \left(\sum_k |||e_k|||\right) \|x-y\|.
$$
So, if $\epsilon > 0$ is given, $\delta = ?$

Comment: Let $ε/δ$=$\sum |||e_{k}|||$ then $(\sum|||e_{k}|||)||x-y||<(\sum|||e_{k}|||)δ<ε$

Comment: Is the last thing -I said- right?

Comment: I really understand well. Thank you so much. You are a good teacher as well. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's much neater if you show that it is lipschitz continuous
$$\|f(x)-f(y)\| = | \, |||x||| - |||y||| \, | \leq 1 \cdot |||x-y|||\leq C \cdot \|x-y\|$$
as all norms are equivalent on finte dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: for the constant $C$ you can use the standard basis and the triangle inequality